# Qual usar "Afim" ou "A fim"?

Tags: ortografia

Quando quero dizer que tenho interesse em uma pessoa o correto seria dizer:

- Afim
- A fim

Qual é o correto?

Comment: Acho que A fim é relacionado à _finalidade_

Comment: corrigido :) :) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A palavra ***afim*** e a expressão ***a fim*** são pronunciadas de forma idêntica. Porém, a grafia delas faz toda a diferença.

***Afim*** é classificada como adjetivo, que significa afinidade, proximidade, semelhança:

> História e Direito são matérias afins.

Por outro lado, a expressão ***a fim*** é classificada como locução prepositiva, cujo significado indica finalidade, objetivo, propósito:

> João estudou a fim de passar na prova.

Fonte: [Aprender Português](http://aprenderportugues.com.br/a-fim-ou-afim-diferenca/)

Answer (score 8):

- ***A fim*** indica finalidade, objetivo, vontade.
- ***Afim*** indica afinidade, semelhança, proximidade.

***Estar a fim de uma pessoa***, neste caso, está relacionado a **ter vontade de** [estar com] **uma pessoa**, e não a **ter afinidade com a pessoa**.

Fonte: http://www.mundoeducacao.com/gramatica/afimou-fim-de.htm

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, usar-se-ia *afim*, que é um substantivo *ou* um adjectivo, dependendo do contexto (neste caso é um adjetivo, acho). *A fim* significa o mesmo que *com o objectivo de* e é uma locução prepositiva.

Comment: Não, pá, enganaste-te. Os brasileiros dizem "estou a fim daquela garota" (aquela garota é objetivo meu; vê também o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/fim)); não dizem "estou afim daquela garota" = "estou com algum parentesco/semelhança relativamene àquela garota"?